# javac no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: java, cmd, javac

Tengo un problema con el comando javac para ver la version, ya instale el sdk y puse todas las variables en su lugar, lo verifique 3 veces.

Tengo el sdk version 14.0.1

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno imagino que te refieres al **JDK** que viene siendo un subconjunto de **SDK** pero bueno ese es otro tema.

Ahora bien cuando hablamos de **javac** nos referimos al compilador que permitirá ejecutar nuestro código fuente, que puedes utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
javac hola.java
```

Si quieres ver la version instalada deberias uilizar:

```
java -version
```

Esto retornará la versión que estas utilizando.

El como asegurarte de que esta configurado correctamente dependerá del sistema operativo que estes utilizando, lo más común es que si estas utilizando windows debas configurar las variables de entorno y añadir la ruta de tu **JDK** más preciso la carpeta **bin** seguramente sera algo asi *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin*.

Ingresa al *(panel de control / Sistema y seguridad / Sistema)* luego presionas la opción *Cambiar configuración* y luego en la pestaña *Opciones avanzadas*, presionas el boton *"variables de entorno"*. Una vez en este punto podrias crear una nueva variable y luego usarla en el path pero haremos algo mas sencillo en esta ocación simplemente busca la variable *path* la seleccionas y presionas *Editar* te posicionas al final del texto y escribes un *punto y coma ";"* y seguidamente pegas la ruta del *JDK* y aceptas las ventanas para guardar tus cambios.

Espero haberme explicado bien ([También puedes encontrar un tutorial aqui](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=389:configurar-java-en-windows-variables-de-entorno-javahome-y-path-cu00610b&catid=68&Itemid=188)). Suerte ;)